# Graphic added/deleted lines by user

Tags: git

I'm wondering if it's possible with Git to get for instance a CSV compatible dataset with the added and removed lines by user depending on the time.

With a command line like this, I can know the lines I have added and removed on the current branch.

`git log --author="Vadorequest" --pretty=tformat: --numstat | gawk '{ add += $1 ; subs += $2 ; loc += $1 - $2 } END { printf "added lines: %s removed lines : %s total lines: %s\n",add,subs,loc }'`

What I am looking for is something like this but that generates a dataset (csv compatible?) with the evolution per day or week.

The aim is to know the evolution of the changes in the source code through the time, to generate statistics per user.

Is that even possible?

I'm thinkink about csv (`;` delimiter) because that's not difficult to use with Excel and generate a graphic with the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is similar to what a project like [**gitstats**](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/examples/gitstats/) does produce: see for instance the [author page for the git repo itself](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/examples/git/authors.html).

Similarly, a project like [**gitinspector**](https://code.google.com/p/gitinspector/) produces similar output, including text files ([like this one](http://wiki.gitinspector.googlecode.com/git/examples/django_output.txt), tsv though -- tab separated --, not csv)

The project [**git_stats**](https://github.com/tomgi/git_stats) (ruby) does include lines added/deleted by author as well, as [in this example](http://tomgi.github.io/git_stats/examples/devise/authors/best_authors.html).

Comment: Thanks for listing several solution, I'll use the ruby `git_stats` gem, since I'm working with ruby it makes sense and the graphics look better. Thanks!